# Is that possible to define "SET NULL" for only one column of composite foreign key in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Postgres supports this feature - [link](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=d6f96ed94e73052f99a2e545ed17a8b2fdc1fb8a). Not sure how to implement it in SQLAlchemy.
If I do `ForeignKeyConstraint(..., ondelete="set null(payment_id)")`, it throws an error:

```
Unexpected SQL phrase: 'set null(payment_id)' (matching against '^(?:RESTRICT|CASCADE|SET NULL|NO ACTION|SET DEFAULT)$')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [PostgreSQL `on delete set null`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-REFERENCES-REFACT-SET-NULL) is not exposed among the SQLAlchemy [cascade](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/cascades.html#) options, because [*it's default behaviour*](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/cascades.html#delete) (of the ORM):

> if our `User.addresses` relationship does *not* have `delete` cascade, SQLAlchemy’s default behavior is to instead de-associate `address1` and `address2` from `user1` by setting their foreign key reference to `NULL`.

So you can just skip `ondelete` entirely, if `set null` is what you want. This SQLAlchemy default overrides PostgreSQL's own default [`NO ACTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-REFERENCES-REFACT-NO-ACTION):

> `NO ACTION`
> Produce an error indicating that the deletion or update would create a foreign key constraint violation. If the constraint is deferred, this error will be produced at constraint check time if there still exist any referencing rows. This is the **default** action.